# What is the currently popular Java SIP library?

Tags: java, sip

I'm working on developing a SIP application in Java and wondering what is the most used SIP library currently.

MJSIP?

Comment: It helps to know what kind of application you have in mind: mobile? desktop? server? You are getting mixed answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, its [JAIN-SIP](http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Communications/JainSIP). Its good to know about MjSip, by the way. You might be interested in looking at [JBoss Mobicent](http://www.mobicents.org-a.googlepages.com/index.html), the user guide is not complete at the moment. and you wouldn't find much help on Mobicent.

Or as [metadaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33905/metadaddy) stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/498307/42769), "You might want to take a look at [SailFin](https://sailfin.dev.java.net/) - its a SIP servlet container built by Ericsson using [GlassFish](http://glassfish.java.net/)."

Answer (score 12):

You might want to take a look at [SailFin](https://sailfin.dev.java.net/) - its a SIP servlet container built by Ericsson using [GlassFish](http://glassfish.java.net/).

Comment: SailFin is indeed a great option. Including this to my answer, if you don't mind, as that is the one coming on top. +1

Answer (score 6):

There is a great SIP stack called [Pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org/), which is written in C, but there is a JNI [wrapper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pjsip-jni/) available, so SIP-specific C functions can be called directly from Java through JNI. It is possible to define callback methods, which can be implemented in your Java application.

Possible performance improvements, code reusablilty (e.g. on Android and iPhone) and active development community are the main benefits for this stack.

An Android SIP VOIP client, [CSipSimple](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/) uses this stack, you can have a look at it.

Comment: JNI wrapper doesnt work.

Comment: It does, in fact in our project.

Comment: It doesnt. tried it and no joy.

Answer (score 2):

if your application is a client application you might be interested by [peers](http://peers.sourceforge.net/), which is a java sip client, simple and documented.

Answer (score 0):

JainSip sip stack have proved to be mature and complete. [Mobicents platform](http://mobicents.org) is a mature platform which using the Jain Sip stack with big active community.