# SIP(session initiation protocol) in Android 2.1

Tags: android, sip

I want to create Dialer for my HTC desire(Android 2.1). i think Android 2.1 does not include SIP Api..so, how can i include SIP API to create SIP Dialer for Android 2.1?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android SIP API is available from API version 9 which is Android 2.3 codename Gingerbread.

So there is no way you can use that API prior to API level 9. You will have to find a SIP library and work with that one.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498043/what-is-the-currently-popular-java-sip-library) might help you find a good library for Java. You will have to test it to find out if it works that well on Android.