# SIP stack for Java

Tags: java, sip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the currently popular Java SIP library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498043/what-is-the-currently-popular-java-sip-library)

I know that this question has already been answered several times, but all the answers are a bit old.

So does anyone have any news on this issue?

Comment: yep, but this question is from 2009, I want to know, if is anything new on this area.